# Replace a String between two Strings

Tags: java, regex

Let's say we have something like:

```
&firstString=someText&endString=OtherText
```

And I would like to replace "someText" with something else. What is the best way to do this considering the fact that I do not know what someText might be (any string) and all I know is that it will be surrounded with &firstString= and &endString=

Edit: sorry looks like this is not clear enough. I do not know what "someText" might be, the only information I have is that it will be between &firstString= and &endString=

I was thinking about using split multiple times but it sounded ugly ..

Comment: What exactly is it that you need to do? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you rebuilding a query string?

Comment: I added a clarification to the question, sorry if it wasn't clear enough :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that has support for regex like this:

```
String newstr = str.replaceAll("(&firstString=)[^&]*(&endString=)", "$1foo$2");
```

Comment: public static String replaceBetween(String theString, String value, String open, String close) {
  return theString.replaceAll("(" + open + ")[^&]*(" + close + ")", "$1" + value + "$2");
 }

Comment: What would be the time performance as compared to using sed or perl commands to replace the string?

Comment: This is Java question so obviously there is no comparison with Unix tools

Answer (score 5):

The easiest to understand way to do it is to search for the delimiters, and cut out a substring between their positions, like this:

```
String str = "&firstString=someText&endString=OtherText";
String firstDelim = "&firstString=";
int p1 = str.indexOf(firstDelim);
String lastDelim = "&endString=";
int p2 = str.indexOf(lastDelim, p1);   // look after start delimiter    
String replacement = "quick_brown_fox";
if (p1 >= 0 && p2 > p1) {
    String res = str.substring(0, p1+firstDelim.length())
               + replacement
               + str.substring(p2);
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
yourString.replace("someText", "somethingElse");
```

**EDIT based on clarification**

```
String x = "&firstString=someText&endString=OtherText";
int firstPos = x.indexOf("&firstString=") + "&firstString=".length();
int lastPos = x.indexOf("&endString", firstPos);
String y = x.substring(0,firstPos) + "Your new text" + x.substring(lastPos);
System.out.println(y);
```

Output:

```
&firstString=Your new text&endString=OtherText
```

Comment: I just clarified the question further. I do not know what sometext might be (I only know the strings around it)

Comment: The title is: "Replace a String between two strings" :) Sorry again if it wasn't clear, my fault :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the question, you should do something like this, but I'm not sure I totally got what you asked:

```
yourString = firstString + replacingString + endString;
```

If you want the "replaced" string:

```
replacedString = wholeString.substring(0, wholeString.lastIndexOf(endString) - 1);
replacedString = tempString.substring(firstString.length() + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution checks that we're not going of the end of the string and will do it for multiple occurrences.

```
 int startIndex = text.indexOf(startDelim);
 while (startIndex > -1)
 {
    int endIndex = text.indexOf(endDelim, startIndex);
    String endPart = "";

    if ((endIndex + endDelim.length()) < text.length())
       endPart = text.substring(endIndex + endDelim.length());

    text = text.substring(0, startIndex) + replacementText + endPart;
    startIndex = text.indexOf(startDelim);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

just replacing the whole `&firstString=someText&` since this includes the outer barriers which I assume to be URL related?

Comment: I just clarified the question further. I do not know what sometext might be (I only know the strings around it)

Comment: @user220755 yeah, then use that regex stuff mentioned by dcp and replace sometext with [^\\&]*

Comment: can you explain a little further?